# Mongoose aggregation improvement

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given this dataset and this mongodb, how to properly convert this aggregation into Mongoose?

I have included, the code using mongoose, which works but I want to know if this is the right way of doing it and that if this aggregation can be improved?

Thanks.

```
db.cars.aggregate(
    //De-normalized the nested array of accounts
    {"$unwind": "$accounts"},
    //De-normalized the nested array of cars
    {"$unwind": "$accounts.cars"},
    //match carId to 3C
    {"$match": {"accounts.cars.carId" : "3C"}},
    //Project the accounts.cars object only
    {"$project" : {"accounts.cars" : 1}}
).pretty();
```

The Mongoose version that I'm trying to improve:

```
Car.aggregate()
  .unwind('accounts')
  .unwind('accounts.cars')
  .match({'accounts.cars.carId' : "3C"})
  .project({"accounts.cars": 1, _id: 0})
  .exec(function (err, carsObj) {});
```

and the dataset (cars):

```
{ 
        "_id" : ObjectId("56223329b64f07a40ef1c15c"), 
        "username" : "john", 
        "email" : "john@john.com", 
        "accounts" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("56322329b61f07a40ef1c15d"), 
                "cars" : [
                    {
                        "carId" : "6A", 
                        "_id" : ObjectId("56323329b64f07a40ef1c15e")
                    },
                    {
                        "carId" : "6B", 
                        "_id" : ObjectId("56323329b64f07a40ef1c15e")
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("56223125b64f07a40ef1c15c"), 
        "username" : "paul", 
        "email" : "paul@paul.com", 
        "accounts" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5154729b61f07a40ef1c15d"), 
                "cars" : [
                    {
                        "carId" : "5B", 
                        "_id" : ObjectId("56323329854f07a40ef1c15e")
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("56322117b61f07a40ef1c15d"), 
                "cars" : [
                    {
                        "carId" : "6G", 
                        "_id" : ObjectId("51212929b64f07a40ef1c15e")
                    },
                    {
                        "carId" : "3C", 
                        "_id" : ObjectId("51273329b64f07a40ef1c15e")
                    },
                    {
                        "carId" : "4N", 
                        "_id" : ObjectId("51241279b64f07a40ef1c15e")
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

What the aggregation returns is:

```
[
  { accounts:
     { cars:
        {
          "carId" : "3C", 
          "_id" : ObjectId("51273329b64f07a40ef1c15e")
        }
     }
  }
]
```

Comment: What do you seem to think "mongoose syntax" means here? The syntax is "identical", where the only exception from what you are writiing is really a general convention that your whole pipeline should actually be enclosed in an array `[]`. There is no difference at all, except again you should probably just be using `$redact` or similar to be more optimal, or even just the positional `$` operator with `.find()` if there is only ever one match per array. Filtering arrays via `$unwind` is not really efficient.

Comment: @BlakesSeven thanks alot, I updated my question with more info and the mongoose code; would you have some suggessions as how this can be improved by using $redact and $ and perhaps by avoiding $unwind ? thanks

Comment: Still completely unclear what you are asking here. Those "helper methods" you are using in mongoose are not "required" and frankly with a dynamic language like JavaScript where to can just directly construct a data sttructure ( what an aggregation pipeline or MongoDB query is ) it doesn't seem intuitive at all. Your new term is "improve", but improve how? What is the intent of the query? What different results are required? I already stated if you only expect a single match per document then you are better of using `.find()` instead.

Comment: @BlakesSeven As per the schema in the dataset, I want to get the retuned object that I have mentioned above. My schema has nested arrays and I believe the .find() along with projection are not able to handle nested arrays to get the same returned obj as above. For that reason I used aggregation so that I can $unwind the arrays and $match and finally to $project. What I mean by "improve" is that I was wondering if there is a way to get the same single match with .find() or without doing $unwind so that the performance can be improved? Thanks again